# Apply a function to next two elements in list

Tags: list, function, haskell

I am writing a function to apply a function for next two elements in list.

For example: `applyToTwo (+) [1,2,3,4]` return `[3,5,7]`.

`applyToTwo (-) [7,1,1,1,1]` return `[6,0,0,0]`.

I want to generalize the type so it could apply to any type I want. My attempt is:

```
applyToTwo :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
applyToTwo f [] = []
applyToTwo f [x] = []
applyToTwo f (x:x1:rest) = f x x1 ++ applyToTwo f (x1:rest)
```

By the way, are there any way to generalize the number of element to apply so it could apply to 3, 4, 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
applyToTwo :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
applyToTwo f [] = []
applyToTwo f [x] = []
applyToTwo f (x:x1:rest) = f x x1 : applyToTwo f (x1:rest)
```

Generalizing to arbitrary arities should be possible, but it requires some advanced type-level hackery.

Comment: As I pointed out in an answer to a similar question, you can replace the first two cases with `applyToTwo f _ = []` if it is listed after the `applyToTwo f (x:x1:rest)` case.

Answer (score 8):

It appears you are simply zipping a list with its tail, so you could use `zipWith`:

```
applyToTwo f xs = zipWith f xs (tail xs)
```